# Google Cloud - How do I import GCP cloud SQL certificates into Secret Manager using Terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-sql, google-secret-manager

My GCP cloud SQL has SSL enabled. With that, my client will require the server CA cert, client cert and key to connect to the database. The client is configured to retrieve the certs and key from Secret Manager.

I am deploying my setup using Terraform. Once the SQL instance is created, it needs to output the certs and key so that I can create them in Secret Manager. However, Secret Manager only takes in string format but the output of the certs and keys are in list format.

I am quite new to Terraform, what can I do to import the SQL certs and key into Secret Manager?

The following are my Terraform code snippets:

**Cloud SQL**

```
output "server_ca_cert" {
  description = "Server ca certificate for the SQL DB"
  value = google_sql_database_instance.instance.server_ca_cert
}

output "client_key" {
  description = "Client private key for the SQL DB"
  value = google_sql_ssl_cert.client_cert.private_key
}

output "client_cert" {
  description = "Client cert for the SQL DB"
  value = google_sql_ssl_cert.client_cert.cert
```

**Secret Manager**

```
module "server_ca" {
  source = "../siac-modules/modules/secretManager"

  project_id = var.project_id
  region_id = local.default_region
  secret_ids = local.server_ca_key
#  secret_datas = file("${path.module}/certs/server-ca.pem")
  secret_datas = module.sql_db_timeslot_manager.server_ca_cert
}
```

**Terraform plan error**
Error: Invalid value for input variable
│
│   on ..\siac-modules\modules\secretManager\variables.tf line 21:
│   21: variable "secret_datas" {
│
│ The given value is not suitable for module.server_ca.var.secret_datas, which is sensitive: string required. Invalid value defined at 30-secret_manager.tf:71,18-63.

Answer (score 0):

eg:

```
resource "google_secret_manager_secret" "my_secret" {
  name     = "my-secret"
  type     = "generic-secret"
  project  = "my-project"
  labels = {
    "env" = "prod"
  }
}

resource "google_secret_manager_secret_version" "secret_version" {
  name       = "secret_version"
  secret     = google_secret_manager_secret.my_secret.id
  project    = "my-project"
  payload    = "c2VjcmV0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by:

1. Exporting the SQL outputs to a file
2. Use data to read the file contents, add dependency to the output. This dependency is key to the setup, the deployment will wait for the SQL to be created and certificate exported before creating the secrets.
3. At secret manager use the data as the content for secret_data

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the value of your output is wrong. You know it's a list, so it should be retrieved like this:

```
output "server_ca_cert" {
  description = "Server ca certificate for the SQL DB"
  value = google_sql_database_instance.instance.server_ca_cert.0.cert
}
```

You can find out more from the doc:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/sql_database_instance#server_ca_cert.0.cert